# Would using a bolt be sufficient to close any loose battery terminals?

Tags: battery, bolts

One of my battery terminals was too small and  the cars battery clamps do not fit tighlty , a mechanic then placed a bolt inbetween the gap and it tightened, would this work provided the bolt is securely tightened?

I think it wont  because after he did it but the battery still got drained.  However the bolt was secure(or seemed to be secure) so I'm just wondering if its secure shouldnt it be working? Or is it difficult to discern whether a bolt in the gaps can be tight enough to do the job hence this doesnt work even as a temp fix?

Thanks

Comment: Autozone sells lead battery terminal caps just for this peculiar problem. They fit over small battery terminals, mechanically makes the terminal and cap fit regular battery cable clamps and allows excellent electrical current conduction.

Answer (score 2):

> One of my battery terminals was too small and the cars battery clamps do not fit tighlty , a mechanic then placed a bolt inbetween the gap and it tightened, would this work provided the bolt is securely tightened?

Then replace the clamp that doesn't fit. That's a 5$ item. A good electrical connection is important, as the currents are *large* - several hundred amps. A poor connection means a lot of energy is wasted at the point of the connection, and with low voltage systems any additional voltage drop is problematic.

> I think it wont because after he did it but the battery still got drained.

If there's a drain, there's a drain. That's not related to how the cable is attached to the battery. Bad cable termination will show up when starting the motor, not as a drain.

Comment: By drain I meant I found the battery to be discharged, probably due to it not recharging due to the poor connection while driving?

Comment: If the connection is so poor that it doesn't charge while driving you would not be able to start the car. Charging current is in tens of amps, starting in hundreds of amps. If the only problem you observe is battery drainage, your problem is that, *not* poor terminal connection.